# Simple isolated eigenvalue and pole of the resolvent

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be bounded linear operator on some complex Banach space, and $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $T$ which is isolated in its spectrum, and such that $\bigcup_{n\ge 1} N((T- \lambda I)^n)$ is one-dimensionnal.

How can we prove that $\lambda$ is a simple pole of the resolvent of $T$ ?

Comment: Dear Ahriman, Can you explain what you mean by $N((T-\lambda)^n)$? Thanks!  Regards,

Comment: This denotes the kernel of the operator $(T-\lambda I)^n$.

Comment: Have a look at Theorems 3 and 4 in Chapter VIII.8. of K. Yosida's "Functional Analysis" (Springer, 1971) which deal with precisely this issue.